# Problem installing SyntaxNet on Ubuntu 18.04.1: Error executing Jupyter command 'nbextension': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter, syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface

I want to use Parsey McParseface, and I'm following the installation instructions for SyntaxNet here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet#ubuntu-1604-binary-installation#ubuntu-1604-binary-installation

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and the first 3 commands worked, but when I try to run

```
python -m jupyter_core.command nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

I get the following error:

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'nbextension': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

(The Readme said to ask questions here using the syntaxnet tag)

I looked up other similar issues on StackOverflow and I've tried adding /home/[username]/.local/bin to PATH but that didn't fix it, as well as running this instead:

```
python -m jupyter_core.command /home/[username]/.local/bin/nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
```

I also tried upgrading jupyter with

```
pip install -U jupyter
```

No matter what I do I still get the same error.

Comment: I ran `/home/[username]/.local/bin/jupyter-nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension` and it looks like it might have worked...